# Find length of a string in SQL using LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string-length

Example:

Suppose there are following rows:

1- Animal is innocent 
 2- Dog is Animal

select length(columnname like %animal%) from tablename

```
o/p - 1-17
      2-13
```

Comment: I read the question several times but I really don't understand what you mean

Comment: Please provide table description, its contents and desired output

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You just need to alter your query a little. The value given to the LENGTH function should the column upon which you wish to calculate the length. The LIKE operator should be used along with a WHERE statement. See code below.

```
SELECT LENGTH(columnname) from tablename WHERE columname LIKE "%animal%"
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: Sure, I've added some further explanation. But, really it's just about using the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select length(columnname) from tablename where lower(columnname) like 'animal%';`
```

This gives you the length of the text in the column, columnname when the columnname value contains the word 'animal'

Comment: Please insert your code inside a code segment so we can upvote your answer. Kindly, Vitali.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when function

```
case when columnname like %animal% then length(columname) else 0 end as lengthNum
```